# Selecting multiple subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have subqueries that need to return different results. Each subqueries used different aggregate functions like `SUM()` AND `COUNT(*)`. What I did is I encapsulate them with `SELECT (SELECT subquery, SELECT subquery)` not sure if this possible.

Expected result:

`TwoYears
  123
   5`

```
SELECT(
(SELECT
(SELECT SUM(AHT)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(year, [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[HireDate], GETDATE()) >= 2 AND (DATEDIFF(year, [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[HireDate], GETDATE())) <= 2 OR (DATEDIFF(year, [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[HireDate], GETDATE())) <= 1
                THEN [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[Value]
    END AS AHT
    FROM [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster] WHERE [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[Month] = 'January'  AND [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[Year] = 2018 AND [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[AccountID] = 8 AND [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[LOBID] = 23
) f
WHERE AHT = AHT ) AS TwoYears),

(SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS TwoYears
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(year, [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[HireDate], GETDATE()) >= 2 AND (DATEDIFF(year, [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[HireDate], GETDATE())) <= 2 OR (DATEDIFF(year, [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[HireDate], GETDATE())) <= 1
                THEN 'Good'
    END AS Result
    FROM [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster] WHERE [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[Month] = 'January'  AND [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[Year] = 2018 AND [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[AccountID] = 8 AND [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[LOBID] = 23
) f
WHERE Result = 'Good') AS TwoYears)
) a
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: Use `UNION ALL` between your 2 selects instead.

Comment: You should union your 2 statements

Comment: @EzLo Already tried that but it throw an error `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: @JohnFrancis Union all is the way to go here, you might have a syntax error when using it. A `SUM()` and a `COUNT()` without a group by will always return 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a union all and remove some of your subselects.

Like this:

```
SELECT SUM(AHT) as TwoYears
                    FROM (
                        SELECT CASE 
                                WHEN DATEDIFF(year, [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[HireDate], GETDATE()) >= 2
                                    AND (DATEDIFF(year, [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[HireDate], GETDATE())) <= 2
                                    OR (DATEDIFF(year, [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[HireDate], GETDATE())) <= 1
                                    THEN [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[Value]
                                END AS AHT
                        FROM [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster]
                        WHERE [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[Month] = 'January'
                            AND [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[Year] = 2018
                            AND [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[AccountID] = 8
                            AND [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[LOBID] = 23
                        ) f
                    WHERE AHT = AHT

                    union all


                    SELECT COUNT(*) AS TwoYears
                    FROM (
                        SELECT CASE 
                                WHEN DATEDIFF(year, [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[HireDate], GETDATE()) >= 2
                                    AND (DATEDIFF(year, [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[HireDate], GETDATE())) <= 2
                                    OR (DATEDIFF(year, [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[HireDate], GETDATE())) <= 1
                                    THEN 'Good'
                                END AS Result
                        FROM [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster]
                        WHERE [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[Month] = 'January'
                            AND [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[Year] = 2018
                            AND [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[AccountID] = 8
                            AND [AgentProfile_CRT].[dbo].[uvw_AHTMaster].[LOBID] = 23
                        ) f
                    WHERE Result = 'Good'
```

Comment: This really works when removing subselect. I thought subselect will be the solution. Appreciated your help :)